# Error: callback function required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, nunjucks

I am trying to render an object into html using node,express and mongodb. when I tried the below code

```
var express=require('express'),
app=express(),
engines = require('consolidate'),
nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('index',{'name':'Hello'});
})

app.use(function(req,res){
res.sendStatus(404);
})

var server = app.listen(3000,function(){
var port=server.address().port;
console.log('Express server listening on port', port);
})
```

I am getting callback function error like below

```
D:\Wiki>node app.js
D:\Wiki\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:174
if ('function' != typeof fn) throw new Error('callback function required');
                       ^

Error: callback function required
at Function.app.engine (D:\Wiki\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:174:
38)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Wiki\app.js:7:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

can someone help me how to render html using nunjucks? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in log - error on line 7 `app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);`. So problem is here.

Add new file e.g. `templateEngine.js`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');

module.exports = function (app) {
    // store environment env
    var env = nunjucks.configure(['views/', 'views2/'], {
        autoescape: true,
        express   : app
    });

    // This is filter example. You can use it by {{varname | myFilter}} in template
    env.addFilter('myFilter', function(text) {
        return text.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

In main js call `require('templateEngine')(app);`

Comment: it says "cannot find module 'templateEngine'

Comment: sry, I had to include "./" before templateEngine. Then I am not getting that error. But what does "callback function required" error mean?

Comment: I think it's means that call `app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks)` is not correct because engines.nunjucks is not a function as required.

Answer (score 2):

Hello fellow mongo university student!
I faced the same issue as well when started on this week 1 lecture. The cause was I installed an incorrect version of *engines* dependency when writing the code from scratch.

Solution is to just clear your project's local node_modules and have just app.js in the root and views folder with the template.

like this :

```
hello_world
 --app.js
 --views
 ----index.html
```

now install the dependencies one by one

```
npm install express
npm install consolidate
npm install nunjucks
```

Finally

```
node app.js  // to start the app.
```

Also you dont have to have ***nunjucks*** as separate dependency in line 4, ***considate***, takes care of this for you.
You should be able to see the app come up fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved by:

1) `npm install consolidate nunjucks --save`

2) define consolidate in app.js/server.js/index.js or whatever you name your main app file:

```
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
```

3) Middleware should be:

```
app.engine('html', consolidate.nunjucks);
app.set('views', './views');
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`nunjucks`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html) docs:

Using express? Simply pass your express app into configure:
    var app = express();

```
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});
```

So you can do (assuming you have a `views` folder in the same directory containing this file):

```
{code...}
var app = express();
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

nunjucks.configure(__dirname + '/views', {...

app.set('view engine', 'html');
{...}
```

Note the use of nodejs `__dirname` to resolve the path.